# Understanding covariance matrix used in gaussian mixture model

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, mixed-model, clustering

Using python's "elliptic envelope" for gaussian mixture clustering (gmm), what does it mean by "spherical, diagonal, etc."? I can imagine that "diagonal" refers to a diagonal covariance matrix where only the diagonal elements are non-zero, but what do "tied, spherical and full" mean?

[image]

[image]